# datatype for mobile no

Tags: database

what is best suited Data type for mobile no. , longitude and  latitude??in Mysql And oracle

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you're not likely to do arithmetic or compare mobile numbers (except for equality) string type seems best. *Length of the string depends on the phone number*

You might consider converting longitude and latitude to decimal values and just using a float.

Comment: Never use numeric types to store phone numbers. In Australia at the very least, phone numbers can start with '0' which gets stripped if you use a numeric type.

Comment: (I realise you don't advocate using a numeric type, I'm just trying to enforce the "Why?" of the choice).

Answer (score 1):

I am going to guess, varchar(16) or longer for mobile no, number(5,3) or longer for Longitude / Latitude ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have to use `Varchar(n)` as datatype of mobile number because some times probably you will have to store mobile number as in `111-111-1111` so at that time `int` will not work, but by using `varchar()` you will never get exception.

Comment: I removed your other (conflicting) answer, as this seems to be the one that you intended. I've also edited your post for brevity.